# Bootstrap progress bar called from javascript error

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a progress bar defined like this:

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
    <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
</div>
```

I am using a javascript code to change the length of the bar simultaneously. Here is the code

```
            var progress = setInterval(function() {
                var percent=(($scope.subcategory.planned2+$scope.subcategory.completed2)/($scope.subcategory.required2)*100);
                var $bar = $('.bar');
                $bar.width($bar.width()+percent);
                $bar.text(percent + "%");
            });
```

I am getting the value of the bar correctly when i run my program but for some reason the bar does not show. It shows an empty progress bar but the value of the `$bar.text` still shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you updated from bootstrap 2 to bootstrap 3?  If so the inner class is wrong, you'll want to use `progress-bar` instead of `bar`.

Comment: thanks..yeah i used the wrong version of the syntax.